# AngularJS controller and service creation

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

Im working on a new Angular project with the following files:

```
//app.js
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['serviceA', 'serviceB', "ctrlA", 'ctrlB']);

//ctrlA.js
var ctlA = angular.module('serviceA', []);
ctlA.controller('menuController', ['$scope', 'serviceA', function($scope, serviceA) {
  // ...
}]);
```

Is there a reason not to do it this way ?

```
//ctrlB.js
angular.module('mainApp')
.controller('ctrlB', ['$scope', 'serviceA', function($scope, serviceA) {
  // ...
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Zenorbi, mentioned is absolutely right. However, thought of adding this information to conclude a better answer.

You can modularize the app into multiple segments to make it easy to understand. The segmentation can be 
done in different ways.

**Based on service types** - this will be useful for small applications

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', [
    'app.controllers',      // Controllers
    'app.directives',       // Directives
    'app.filters',          // Filters
    'app.services'          // Services
]);
```

Example implementation of a module.

```
var ctrls = angular.module('app.controllers');
ctrls.controller('menuController', ['$scope', 'serviceA', function($scope, serviceA) {
  // ...
}]);
```

**According to the purpose of each module.** For example, you can separate chart related classes to a separate module and isolate it from the main code base. This will allow parallel programming by someone else, as this module can act independent from the parent module.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  Its a new app and the modules don't have the best names yet, as we are figuring stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

Both implementations are valid, but the module system is there to make sure you separate a bigger application into modules. If serviceA, serviceB, ctrlA and ctrlB are closely related, you might as well bundle them into a module. If you want to have your services elsewhere, you may create a module called `mainApp.services`.

It is up to you, how you structure the code, but modules exist for a reason. To have more than one "thing" in them.